# Road Cycling on a Gravel Path

Tags: bicycling

Recently I have started cycling on a new route. About half of it is road but the other half is sort of a gravel path. It is not bumpy (I'm on a road bike here) but it is certainly not smooth like a road- it is still listed as a cycle route. How much do you reckon that this will take of my speed if I am cycling say around 30km/h?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Impossible to really tell. If you increase your effort, it won't take anything away from speed. Other than that, the condition of the road will dictate how much speed will change. Use the same effort and see what happens to your speed, that will tell you.